# when /proc/cpuinfo begin to update all the time, especially the field "cpu MHz"?

Tags: linux, proc, history, cpu-frequency

I saw that `/proc/cpuinfo` update all the time, especially the field "cpu MHz"? I assumed that these details should be constant.

When did `/proc/cpuinfo` begin to update all the time, especially the field "cpu MHz"? Is it depend linux systems or versions?

Example :

- First run

  ```
  [omerha@hroor tmp]$ cat /proc/cpuinfo  | grep "cpu MHz" | tail -1
  cpu MHz         : 1406.195
  ```
- Second run

  ```
  [omerha@hroor tmp]$ cat /proc/cpuinfo  | grep "cpu MHz" | tail -1
  cpu MHz         : 1675.964
  ```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does "cpu MHz" field mean in the /proc/cpuinfo of a hyper-threading cpu?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/295292/what-does-cpu-mhz-field-mean-in-the-proc-cpuinfo-of-a-hyper-threading-cpu)

Comment: @binarysta That answers what, but not when.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the processor architecture. For x86 (32-bit a.k.a. i386 or 64-bit a.k.a x86_64 a.k.a. amd64), it was generalized in kernel [2.6.16](https://kernelnewbies.org/Linux_2_6_16) which came out in March 2006. The [patch generalizing it](https://lwn.net/Articles/162548/) had been under discussion and review for a while.

In the code (for 32-bit x86): [2.6.16](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v2.6.16/source/arch/i386/kernel/cpu/proc.c#L100) calls [`cpufreq_quick_get`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v2.6.16/source/drivers/cpufreq/cpufreq.c#L841) which looks up the current value for each CPU. [2.6.15](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v2.6.15/source/arch/i386/kernel/cpu/proc.c#L90) reads a global variable which is only updated on some processors and is never updated on multiprocessor machines.

Comment: ... and the x86 code has changed quite a bit since then, see especially [x86 / CPU: Always show current CPU frequency in /proc/cpuinfo](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=7d5905dc14a87805a59f3c5bf70173aac2bb18f8).

Comment: I think it would be helpful to also clarify that the value in `/proc/cpuinfo` is the _current_ clock speed, and is constantly updated, not a static value.

Comment: @terdon Uh? The question is asking since when this is the case, so that's already established.

Comment: @StephenKitt Oh, so this was no longer the case in 4.13 and 4.14, then back in 4.15?

Comment: The situation evolved quite a bit between 2.6.16 and 4.12, with different meanings for the `cpu MHz` value depending on the frequency governor, specific CPU, ACPI support etc. Len Brown tried to [make things consistent](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=51204e0639c4), but that got [reverted](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=890da9cf0983), and Rafael J. Wysocki introduced [the `arch_freq_prepare_all` system](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=7d5905dc14a8) in 4.15.

Comment: All that happened in the 4.13, 4.414 and 4.15 cycles, but the situation was already complicated before then ;-).

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' the question also says " I assumed that these details should be constant.", so I think this is part of what is confusing the OP.

Answer (score 1):

There is no file to update. The CPU frequency changes when it changes.

The "file", it looks like a file but is not a file: it does not exist on disk or SSD. It has a filename, it has content (so it is a file, and so is a directory, a sym-link, a hard-disk, a serial-port, … ). **In general values in `/proc` are generated dynamically whenever they are read.**